# Is there a shell script equivalent of prctl (PR_SET_PDEATHSIG, SIGKILL) for handling zombie children?

Tags: bash, sh

C and C++, I've been using `prctl(PR_SET_PDEATHSIG, SIGKILL);` and it works great.When I spawn child processes in shell scripts I use something like this:

```
    pid=$!
    
    trap "kill $pid" SIGHUP SIGINT SIGTERM
    
    wait
```

Which works in all cases *except* when the shell script gets a SIGKILL (which it can't catch). Then I end up with the children of the shell script being zombies.

Is there a way for shell scripts to have SIGKILL passed on to their children?

I'm pretty open to what shell this would apply to but ideally it'd be bash or sh.

**UPDATE**

So based on the comment below I'm gonna provide some background and see if perhaps I should be using a different approach entirely.  Our setup is structured roughly along these lines:

```
+ systemd
 + a_c_process
   + a_c_process
   + a_c_process
     + a_leaf_c_process
   + shellscriptA
     + a_leaf_c_process
     + a_leaf_c_process
```

So while SIGTERM can be our starting signal (e.g. any non leaf c process could send SIGTERM to all its children when it received a SIGTERM), but if a process in the tree doesn't handle SIGTERM properly my understanding is I should expect systemd to deliver a SIGKILL.  We've been using PR_SET_PDEATHSIG to ensure the entire process tree is cleared of zombies.

From what I can see this technique *should* be able to co-exist with SIGTERM handling.  That is, I can install SIGTERM handlers, but also have PR_SET_DEATHSIG as a fallback if those handlers fail.

Comment: Which is why you should basically never use `SIGKILL`.

Comment: Even in C and C++ you will often see a "Grim Reaper" function which loops through an array of PIDs explicitly killing children.  Note that `prctl` is not POSIX standard.

Answer (score 2):

As noted everywhere, Bash won't allow trapping of KILL, but you can spawn another process to monitor for that. There are several things you can do, such as a watchdog, but I like a solution based on [this Unix & Linux answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/372581/4323) which uses `strace` to monitor the parent process:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

function handlekill() {
        echo "I was KILLed!"
}

curpid=$$
( strace -p $curpid -e 'trace=!all' 2>&1 | grep -q SIGKILL && handlekill )&

sleep 60
echo done
```

If you then `kill -9` that process, you'd get the output "I was KILLed!". The rest is just wiring.

Caveats:

- Need `strace` installed.
- Won't work on modern Linuxes unless the Kernel's [YAMA `ptrace_scope`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/security/Yama.txt) is disabled or you only run the script as root.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is [orphan processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orphan_process).

If the shell script is the supervisor, and the shell script *itself* is killed, it will not be able to supervise it's children anymore.

What happens to the processes is that they are now orphans, and the responsibility falls back on PID 1, the init program of the OS. (This is the reason Docker containers with multiple processes benefit from being started with an [init process](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/). Bash is not good at handling that job.)

I was going to suggest you systemd, so it's a lucky thing you're already using it.
Here is a relevant blog post: http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/systemd-for-admins-4.html

As far as I know, systemd handles orphans. I did a little experiment to confirm:

```
# echo '#!/bin/sh

tail -f /dev/null &
tail -f /dev/null &
tail -f /dev/null &

wait' > /usr/local/bin/orphan
# chmod +x /usr/local/bin/orphan
# echo '[Unit]
Description=Orphan process experiment

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/orphan' > /etc/systemd/system/orphan.service
# systemctl start orphan.service
# systemctl status orphan.service
● orphan.service - Orphan process experiment
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/orphan.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-02-12 17:51:07 UTC; 1s ago
   Main PID: 226742 (orphan)
      Tasks: 4 (limit: 38298)
     Memory: 1.1M
     CGroup: /system.slice/orphan.service
             ├─226742 /bin/sh /usr/local/bin/orphan
             ├─226744 tail -f /dev/null
             ├─226745 tail -f /dev/null
             └─226746 tail -f /dev/null

Feb 12 17:51:07 localhost systemd[1]: Started Orphan process experiment.
# kill -9 226742
# systemctl status orphan.service
● orphan.service - Orphan process experiment
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/orphan.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: signal) since Wed 2020-02-12 17:52:51 UTC; 9s ago
    Process: 226742 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/orphan (code=killed, signal=KILL)
   Main PID: 226742 (code=killed, signal=KILL)

Feb 12 17:51:07 localhost systemd[1]: Started Orphan process experiment.
Feb 12 17:52:51 localhost systemd[1]: orphan.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/K>
Feb 12 17:52:51 localhost systemd[1]: orphan.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
# ps aux | grep tail
root      227721  0.0  0.0   6288  2196 pts/3    S+   17:54   0:00 grep --color=auto tail
```

Success. systemd cleaned up the orphans.

Whether systemd does this by means of [cgroups](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/ControlGroupInterface/) or [subreaper](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/250153/what-is-a-subreaper-process) I don't know. I'm guessing the former.

---

It seems this crazy scientist has implemented a subreaper in Go: https://medium.com/@william.la.martin/dont-fear-the-subreaper-19c8127c031e. That could be a route to go if you're feeling particularly wicked.

---

As a final note, this whole ordeal with orphans and related concepts is the reason I enjoy systemd-logind's [KillUserProcesses=yes](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/logind.conf.html#KillUserProcesses=). It gives me certainty that no matter what kind of things software has been doing while I was logged in, lingering processes will be cleaned up on logout. Peace of mind.